# Proving Cauchy when given a sequence

Tags: analysis

Let $\left\{x_n\right\}$ be a sequence and $0 < a < 1$. Suppose that for all $n \ge 3$ we have

$$
\left\lvert x_n - x_{n-1}\right\rvert \le a\left\lvert x_{n-1} - x_{n-2} \right\rvert.
$$

Prove that $\left\{x_n\right\}$  is Cauchy.

I don't even know where to start here. To prove a sequence is cauchy I have to somehow reach the conclusion of $\left\lvert x_m - x_{k}\right\rvert < \varepsilon$ right? How do I even do that with this inequality. I'm completely lost.

Comment: The triangle inequality is _very_ useful here.

Comment: Consider $|x_n-x_{n-1}|$ as a geometric sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$|x_m-x_k|\le |x_m-x_{m-1}|+|x_{m-1}-x_{m-2}|+\cdots|x_{k+1}-x_k|$$

and

$$|x_n-x_{n-1}|\le a|x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}|\le a^2|x_{n-2}-x_{n-3}|\le\cdots \le a^{n-1}|x_1-x_0|$$